# ROS Tutorial Creating Package Command Not Found

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm following this ROS tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) and everything is working fine until I input "roscd beginner_tutorials" at the end of section 5.1 and get the error "roscd: command not found". I don't know enough about ROS to know exactly what lines do what and how important they are, but I think this line changes the current directory to beginner tutorials. I'm not sure if this is an important error but I've been searching for solutions for the past 30 minutes to no avail. For now I'm continuing the tutorial ignoring this error but if anyone can help solve this error, it would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236733/ros-tutorial-creating-package-command-not-found/) by [Syngerical](https://answers.ros.org/users/27138/syngerical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you get the appropriate output when you run `rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`  from step 5.1 of the tutorial?

It sounds like your ROS environment is not setup properly. Make sure you have correctly followed Step 2 from the earlier tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment), and added the command `source /opt/ros/<distro>/setup.bash` to your `.bashrc` file (with your proper distribution entered. e.g. Indigo).

Doing so will ensure all the ROS commands (e.g. roscd, rospack, etc.) are available each time you open a new terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0